# How to create $_FILES array from url

Tags: php, arrays, file, upload

I've been searching but with no result.
I've got images on one server and I've got their URLs.
I need to download them and create $_FILES array - the same as for uploading files in a form.
could anyone help me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you just send the URLs to the server, let it download the images (using `cURL` or `file_get_contents`)?

Comment: I'm using wordpress I need it for wp_handle_upload function. Here is the reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_handle_upload

Comment: You can fake it up to a point, but if the function you refer to uses `move_uploaded_file` (which would not be surprising) then it can tell that you are faking it and this idea will not work.

Comment: Well i worded once on something similar can't remember the details but wordpress also allows you to add images programmatically directly from URL. Check media_sideload_image function in WP or maybe read here a little bit more: http://theme.fm/2011/10/how-to-upload-media-via-url-programmatically-in-wordpress-2657/

Comment: Thank you, StudioArena. I spent a lot of time to figure out how it works. I've been creating my own functions, downloading others. About 200 lines of code I replaced with this one function and now it works perfect. How can I vote for your reputation? You really helped me. Thanks again.